# Network-manager openconnect with pulse/saml/azure?

Tags: network-manager, vpn, openconnect, azure

I succesfully used the NetworkManager OpenConnect VPN to connect to our Secure Pulse.

However, we recently moved to Azure SAML Login, which is browser-based, and runs on a url in the form: `gateway.company.com/azure`

I found next project, which is able to build the VPN through a browser, but it is run command-line only.

https://github.com/utknoxville/openconnect-pulse-gui

Is there a solution where I can use the NetworkManager to use a Web-UI based login for Pulse?

Comment: Similar issue here, using OpenVPN CLoud with external SAML 2.0 setup, is possible to OpenVPN connection when it force a login using a browser session?